# Deciphering the relationship between two entities from the ERD

Tags: erd

I want to understand the relationship expressed by the following figure:
[image]

The o in front of the employee box means zero or one and the | in front of the department means 1 or more. But I am not sure how to express it.
Some things I thought about this could mean:

- A department can have no employees
- An Employee can work in one or more departments (Not sure if this is true)
- A department can have many employees
  Need some input on the above.

Comment: This is how understand the above diagram: "An Employee works in **one or more** Departments. A Department can have **zero or more** Employees."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a many to many relationship.  The o and the |  tell about optional or mandatory elements, more precisely that:

- a department can have several employees working in it, but could also have none;
- an employee must work in at least one department, and can work in several.

By the way, it's worth discovering more about [Crow's foot ERD notation](https://vertabelo.com/blog/crow-s-foot-notation/)